# Jenkins parameterized input in stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, devops

I know how to request for the user input for the whole pipeline using `parameters` directive. Now i want to be able to request for the user input inside a specific stage and be able to access that value inside the stage. Here's my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            when{
                beforeAgent true
                expression {
                    timeout (time: 30, unit: "SECONDS"){
                        input message: 'Should we continue?', ok: 'Yes',
                            parameters:[[
                                        $class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                        choices: ['Stable release', 'SNAPSHOT'],
                                        description: 'Which Version?',
                                        name: 'version'
                                    ]]
                            }
                            return true
                        }
                    }
            agent any
            steps {
                echo 'Checking dependencies ...'
                echo "${params}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this pipeline I'm able to prompt the user to choose between *Stable release* and *SNAPSHOT* inside *Stage 1* stage. However I'm not able to access this variable using `${params.version}`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the problem and read the input chosen by user as in the following pipeline:

```
def version //define a global variable for the whole pipeline.
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            when{
                beforeAgent true
                expression {
                    timeout (time: 30, unit: "SECONDS"){
                        //Assign the variable here.
                        version = input message: 'Should we continue?', ok: 'Yes',
                            parameters:[[
                                        $class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                        choices: ['Stable release', 'SNAPSHOT'],
                                        description: 'Which Version?',
                                        name: 'v'
                                    ]]
                            }
                            return true
                        }
                    }
            agent any
            steps {
                // And finally access it.
                echo "${version}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```